# What is the best way to parse a .c file?

Tags: file, parsing

I am looking for ideas and examples about how to parse a ".C" file.

Apparently there is no easy way to do this. My goal is to parse a file, find a line and replace the wording of that line.

Any ideas? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is a `.C` file?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to parse a file to replace some text in it. A utility like sed can do it easily with either a literal string or a regular expression.

Otherwise any decent text editor will do it

Comment: I am trying to do a quick app for users without script knowledge, easier for them, and yes that's exactly the goal, do what "sed" does using a gui instead.....